# Getting id of imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I am making a number of imageViews programmatically in a loop and assigning them ids. But when in onClick method I need to get the id of images, it is returning the id of the last image only. How do I get the id of the image that is clicked?

The code I am using:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    imageUrl = "http://ondamove.it/English/images/users/";
    imageUrl = imageUrl + listObject.get(j).getImage();

    image = new ImageView(this);
    image.setPadding(20, 10, 0, 0);
    image.setId(j+1);
    tr.addView(image);
    try {
        new DownloadFileAsync(image, new URL(imageUrl))
                .execute(imageUrl);
        images.add(image);
        //images = new ImageView[5];
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    tr.addView(image);
    table.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    image.setOnClickListener(clickImageListener);
```

Following is the onclicklistener.

```
private OnClickListener clickImageListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        imageId = image.getId();
        Intent fullScreenIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),FullImageActivity.class);
        fullScreenIntent.putExtra(ProfilePageNormalUser.class.getName(),imageId);
        ProfilePageNormalUser.this.startActivity(fullScreenIntent);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `onClick(View v)` method you can call `v.getId()` - this will return you the ID of the `View` being clicked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < image.length; i++)
    {
       if (image[i].getId() == v.getId())
       {
           index = i;
           break;
       }
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Image clicked index => "+index, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```